# Custom report based on query string in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I thought this would be pretty simple but i can't really figure out how to use a query string to create a custom report.

I have multiple pages where all have a query string called `?platform=`. There may be other query strings as well and "platform" may not be the first one.

All I want to do is to create a report where I can see all visits that has a page with the `?platform=` query string as a landing page. Then I want to be able to click on each possible value of the platform parameter and get separate stats from that.

I guess it's very similar to the "search" query parameter feature but I already use that for search.

I also know I could create an custom event or a custom variable and track it that way but it feels a bit weird since it already is a parameter in the URL that Analytics knows about.

I've found some data in the "Behavior -> Path" metric but i can't really figure out to make Analytics treat is as a "filter" more or less so I can drill down into the the value of the query string.

Answer (score 2):

Create custom report via "Personalization":

- add metrics and dimensions at your gusto
- filter by Destination Page
- match type Regex
- filter `/\?platform` (This might need tweaking if "platform" is not always the first parameter in the URL.)